# multiple commands in if statement

Tags: batch-file

I get syntax error while trying to run multiple statements within conditional if of batch script

```
@echo off


set COMMITTIME=%date:~-4%-%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-10,2%-%time:~-11,2%-%time:~-8,2%-%time:~-5,2%
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set COMMITTIME=!COMMITTIME:^ =0!
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion


if %time:~-11,2% LEQ 5 (
echo NB /b
echo Who /b
echo ok) 

echo %time:~-11,2%

if %time:~-11,2% GTR 5 (
echo Normal /b
echo menot /b
echo NOK)


::Nightly build time is less than 5 Am CET
if %time:~-11,2% LEQ 15(   
echo  ERROR commiting ec_baic /b
echo  ERROR commiting ec_baic /b
echo  ERROR commiting ec_baic)
```

In the batch script below first two conditional if works but the third conditional if yeids systex error

```
13
Normal /b
menot /b
NOK
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

Comment: I voted to close this question since the error is caused by a simple typo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a `rem` in from of that `@echo off` and let the debugging begin :-)

More seriously, you'll notice *one* difference between the working and non-working statements, it's the space between then `if` condition and the opening parenthesis.

And, in fact, when I put that in, the error disappears:

```
rem                    +-- This is important
rem                    V
if %time:~-11,2% LEQ 15 (
```